# Selecting Distinct from two tables

Tags: vb.net

I have a table `tblConsentQuestion` with questions

```
intID   nvcText      bitActive
17      Question1    True
18      Question2    True
19      Question3    False
```

and a table `tblConsentData` with the questions for every customer

```
intID   intCustomerID   bitConsent      intIDQuestion 
14      1               False           19
15      1               True            18
```

`WHERE tblConsentQuestion.intID = tblConsentData.intIDQuestion`

I would like to retrieve in a VB.net dataset:

1. all `tblConsentData` for a specific customer i.e, two records with `intID = 14` and `15`
2. all active (`bitActive = true`) records in `tblConsentQuestion` `WHERE 
   tblConsentData.intIDQuestion <> tblConsentQuestion.intID`, in this case only `intID = 17` record (in addition to the two records)

The output should be:

```
Question3   False
Question2   True
Question1   Null
```

I tried something like:

```
str = "Select tblConsentQuestion.intID, bitConsent, nvcText" & fungGetLangId() & " AS nvcqText " _
    & " From tblConsentData " _
    & " Left OUTER JOIN tblConsentQuestion " _
    & " On tblConsentData.intIDQuestion = tblConsentQuestion.intID " _
    & " where tblConsentData.intCustomerID = " & intCustomerID & " " _
    & " UNION ALL " _
    & " Select tblConsentQuestion.intID, -1, nvcText" & fungGetLangId() & " " _
    & " From tblConsentQuestion " _
    & " Left OUTER JOIN tblConsentData " _
    & " On tblConsentData.intIDQuestion = tblConsentQuestion.intID " _
    & " WHERE(tblConsentQuestion.bitActive = 'True') "
```

and I received all active records in `tblConsentQuestion`, whereas I should not receive records with `intID = 18`, which exist in `tblConsentData`.

Comment: What database are you using? Microsoft Access? SQL Server? MySQL? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of `bitActive`? Is it a text field with two possible strings: `'True'` and `'False'`? Or is it an Access Yes/No field?

If the latter, then your SQL shouldn't check for the string values, but rather for the `True` / `False` constants (let's say that `fungGetLangId:

```
WHERE tblConsentQuestion.bitActive = True
```

Or, better yet, you can check the yes/no field directly:

```
WHERE tblConsentQuestion.bitActive
```

Comment: We are working in VB.net and bitActive is Boolean with possible values True or False

Comment: @JohnPapaioannou Yes, but that still doesn't answer which database you are running SQL queries against. You can tell by looking at which connection / command / reader objects you are using, and by the connection string.